# Hadoop fs -put has DataStreamer Exception java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: hadoop, docker-compose

I have started the following docker containers

```
namenode  
datanode1  
datanode2  
datanode3
```

When I attempt to put a file into HDFS as follows I get this error

```
hdfs dfs -put /tmp/airline-2008.csv.bz2 hdfs://namenode.bigdatacluster.com:8020/data/
```

> 17/09/28 22:49:01 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
>   java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
>           at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
>           at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:226)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1591)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1547)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:658) put:
>   java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle java doc,

```
Unchecked exception thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a network operation upon an unresolved socket address
```

That means hostname namenode.bigdatacluster.com used in hdfs URL is not getting resolved to IP address. You may resolve this by adding host to IP mapping to `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: You were right.I figured this out too. The embedded DNS in docker discovery service can resolve those DNS entries but the HDFS API calls never reach to that point on discovery service point and simply fail.  Instead of adding entries in {/etc/hosts} (since IP's will change on every reboot),I configured a Virtual network for all machines to talk to each other and modified core-site.conf file to use machine address on this network.